# Retrieving the value of array which is returned as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following array stored at the front end.

```js
myArr[0] = new Array("AF", "B", "C", "D", "EM", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J");
myArr[1] = new Array("C", "DD", "M", "ED", "F", "DG", "B", "C", "D", "C");
myArr[2] = new Array("F", "G", "H", "I", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J");
```

i need to get the value of the elements in an array. for example myArr[0][0] should return AF. unfortunately i am getting the position to be find of the array as string of array as follows from a service call.

```
["myArr[1][6]", "myArr[3][4]", "myArr[4][2]"]
```

how do i convert this and get the value at the array positions mentioned above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you getting the second array?

Comment: Is the service that you call something you can amend? The response isn't ideal. You'd be better receiving the positions instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to execute strings as script:

```
eval("myArr[1][6]") // gives "C"
```

See codepen here: https://codepen.io/jenko3000/pen/NZJRYK

Be careful though, executing strings as scripts is [dangerous](https://medium.com/@eric_lum/the-dangerous-world-of-javascripts-eval-and-encoded-strings-96fd902af2bd).

Comment: why the downvote? this is totally acceptable if it's safe to do it

Comment: Why did you post a codepen? Couldn't you use a stack snippet?

Comment: I guess, I just find codepens easier to work with. The snippets are horribly clunky.

Comment: They can be, but the downsides to a codepen are that you have to open a new page and open up devtools to check the console.

Comment: True enough... swings and roundabouts eh

Comment: Haha, exactly :P

Comment: @WillJenkins Can you edit your answer? I down-voted your answer by accident it seems. There was one above yours (or below) that was complete nonsense. Not sure how I went for both of them. Sorry dude!

Comment: just added a link to mdn - that sort of thing?

Comment: @WillJenkins Awesome, that's me removed my -1. Sorry again. I wanted you to edit it because 10 minutes elapsed and my vote was locked until you edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to "extract" the two indices and then use them to get the values like so:

```js
let myArr = [];
myArr[0] = new Array("AF", "B", "C", "D", "EM", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J");
myArr[1] = new Array("C", "DD", "M", "ED", "F", "DG", "B", "C", "D", "C");
myArr[2] = new Array("F", "G", "H", "I", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J");

let arr = ["myArr[1][6]", "myArr[2][4]", "myArr[0][2]"];

let res = arr.map(str => {
  let [x, y] = str.match(/(\d+)/g);
  return myArr[x][y];
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to over-complicate the issue. A simple [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over each value and [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)uate will suffice:

```js
const myArr = [
  ["AF", "B", "C", "D", "EM", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"],
  ["C", "DD", "M", "ED", "F", "DG", "B", "C", "D", "C"],
  ["F", "G", "H", "I", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]
]

var positions = ["myArr[1][6]", "myArr[2][4]", "myArr[0][2]"]

positions = positions.map(eval)

console.log(positions)
```

> Note, we can use the shorthand `.map(eval)` over `.map(e => eval(e))` because we are only passing one element to one function, so the shorthand will do that for us.
>
> Also, as [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56987102/10445697) pointed out, eval can be dangerous, as eval can execute malicious scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This code will replace the positions stored in the array with their respective values.

```js
let myArr=[]
myArr[0] = new Array("AF", "B", "C", "D", "EM", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J");
myArr[1] = new Array("C", "DD", "M", "ED", "F", "DG", "B", "C", "D", "C");
myArr[2] = new Array("F", "G", "H", "I", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J");
let values=["myArr[1][6]", "myArr[2][4]", "myArr[0][2]"];
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
  values[i]=eval(values[i])
}
console.log(values)
```